# Is it possible to change the destination coordinates of the imageview while animating

Tags: android, animation, imageview, android-animation

In my application i am able to animate the image from source location to destination location and repeating the animation 5 times using `animation.setRepeatCount(5);`
But i want to change the destination location(yDelta) after each repetition.

For example :
destination Ydelta is 2,  after first repetition need to change the ydelta to 3 and next repetition ydelta to 4 so on... up to 5 repetitions....

Below is my animation code:

```
int sourceCoords[] = new int[2];
int targetCoords[] = new int[2];
int xDelta;
int yDelta;

sourceImage.getLocationOnScreen(sourceCoords);
targetImage.getLocationOnScreen(targetCoords);
xDelta = targetCoords[0] - sourceCoords[0];
yDelta = targetCoords[1] - sourceCoords[1];

sourceImage.bringToFront();
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, xDelta, 0, yDelta);
animation.setDuration(400);
animation.setFillAfter(false);
animation.setRepeatCount(5);
sourceImage.startAnimation(animation);
animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(final Animation animation) {
        sourceImage.bringToFront();     
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    }

});
```

Comment: reputation? what reputation? you mean repetition? if you need some non trivial animation then extend Animation class and override applyTransformation  method

Comment: can you post sample code for my case...